# TinyMCE Filtered Html is stripping in line styles

Tags: wysiwyg

Is there anyway to allow inline styles.  When setting a table width, using the Table icon width field, the width gets set as an inline style for the table tag, and that gets stripped out.  How frustrating!

Anybody have any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

if you use filtered html it is by default remove any inline styles or class attribute also javascript tags
you have to make it full html that allowed style
If you want to use filterd html you can use [wysiwyg_filter](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_filter) module

It give you control which attibute you can use so you can add inline style